# Doctrine Load Module Exception

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm new to doctrine. I created an bootstrap file like the following one:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../conf/general.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/Doctrine/lib/Doctrine.php');
spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));

$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_VALIDATE, Doctrine::VALIDATE_ALL); 
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true); #for accessor  overriding
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true); #in order to be able to use the XTable classes
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING,    Doctrine_Core::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE); #to conservatively load files
$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_EXPORT, Doctrine::EXPORT_ALL); 

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=".DBNAME.";host=".DBHOST;
$dbh = new PDO( $dsn, DBUSERNAME, DBPASS );
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection( $dbh ); 
Doctrine_Core::loadModels('doc_models'); #In order to be able to work with models
```

```
php bootstrap.php
```

command works just as expected.
But I have a file X.php under directory Y and i require bootstrap.php file in X.php ;but when i ran the X.php in the directory Y like

```
 php X.php
```

I got the following exception:

```
Doctrine_Exception: You must pass a valid path to a directory containing Doctrine models in /path_to_directory_of_bootstrap_file/Doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Core.php on line 635
```

Now, how can i fix this issue?

BTW, when i put X.php and bootstrap.php in the same directory it works as expected.
I also tried to require with absolute paths but this didn't solve my problem. I'm testing on Ubuntu 9.10 and installed doctrine from pear. Doctrine version is 1.2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using absolute paths while requiring? [Realpath](https://www.php.net/realpath) can help you create those paths.

Comment: I tried absolute paths and got no use.Sorry I forgot to mention in my post, i'll update the post. BTW when i change my directory with chdir to the directory of bootstrap.php, it seems to work. But it looks awkward to me to use chdir and change the path of file in every file which is requiring the bootstrap.php . I think, there must be better solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error gets triggered when doctrine is expecting some model directories to exist. The error also occurs if you try to generate SQL from a schema.yml BEFORE you have built the model classes. When the model classes get built they create a bunch of directories and it's these that i think you are missing.